# Invalid memory access error from JNA and DLL

Tags: java, dll, jna

I am having trouble with JNA and a DLL file created from LabVIEW. I am able to call it when I don't use this line, the first one:

```
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(FirstPath);
    BufferedWriter writing = new BufferedWriter(writer);
    writing.write("Here goes my strings");
    writing.close();
```

After this the DLL class is followed as:

```
   DLLClass dll = (DLLClass)Native.loadLibrary("DLLFile",DLLClass.class);
   dll.myMethodInsideDLLClass(FirstPath,SecondPath,ThirdPath);
```

It looks that it's trying to access some random FirstPath or I don't know what. It gives me this error.

```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
   at com.sun.jna.Native.getStringBytes(Native Method)
   at com.sun.jna.Native.getString(Native.java:2224)
   at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getString(Pointer.java:681)
   at com.sun.jna.Function.invokeString(Function.java:667)
   at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:434)
   at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:361)
   at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:265)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.myMethodInsideDLLClass(Unknown Source)
```

I mean how in the world can I access the same file I am trying to write to and then call it again in the dll method? I tried and nothing worked. Can someone help me? I would appreciate this very much!

Note: This is my DllClass:

```
  public interface DLLClass extends Library{

  public int myMethodInsideDLLClass(String 
  FirstPath, String SecondPath, String ThirdPath);
  }
```

extends Libray comes from jna.jar.

This is what inside my FileDll.h file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


int32_t __cdecl myMethodInsideDLLClass(
    char FirstPath[], char SecondPath[], 
    char ThirdPath[]);


MgErr __cdecl LVDLLStatus(char *errStr, int errStrLen, void *module);

void __cdecl SetExcursionFreeExecutionSetting(Bool32 value);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif

#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please show us your mapping for the method `dll.myMethodInsideDLLClass()`, particularly what type you have assigned to the arguments.

Comment: I added it. That should be all.

Comment: JNA may need to know the proper character encoding to correctly map a `String` to the appropriate native mapping.  Try adding `W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS` to your DLL loading statement.

Comment: My loading statement? I am sorry.   DLLClass dll = (DLLClass)Native.loadLibrary("DLLFile",DLLClass.class,W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS ); Something like this? I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: Yep, exactly that. I answered in more detail in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

After you have tried Daniel's suggestion, and in case it does not work, please try this:

Replace this line:

```
public interface DLLClass extends Library
```

With this line:

```
public interface DLLClass extends com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary
```

Another potential problem that I can think of is that you might be using a somewhat recent version of java, but your version of JNA is old, or your version of library "DLLFile" is old, and it does not know that the internal representation of java strings has changed in recent java versions, storing the bytes in whatever encoding was used at the time of creation instead of always UTF16.  But this is really grasping at straws here.

Comment: Ah, good option.  Or just copy the function mapper lines from the source for `StdCallLibrary`...

Comment: Got this error. -_-. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
 at com.sun.jna.Native.getStringBytes(Native Method)
 at com.sun.jna.Native.getString(Native.java:2224)

Comment: I tried everything I can think of but nothing worked.

Comment: I am afraid that the use of AWT might be complicating things.  Try moving your code to a as small as possible standalone (console) application and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace gives a strong hint at the source of the problem.

```
at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getString(Pointer.java:681)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invokeString(Function.java:667)
```

If you look at the [JNA source for `invokeString()`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/cc1acdac02e4d0dda93ba01bbe3a3435b8933dab/src/com/sun/jna/Function.java#L659) you'll see it's calling the `getString()` method, assuming 1-byte character encoding (ASCII).  But Windows by default uses a 2-byte Unicode character encoding, and this method needs to know to use a wide string so it will call `getWideString()`.

This can be addressed by assigning the appropriate Type Mapper when loading the DLL.  The easiest way to do this is to add the default Windows type mapping:

```
DLLClass dll = (DLLClass) Native.loadLibrary("DLLFile", DLLClass.class,
    W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
```

That is the standard way of doing it with a WinAPI method.  Technically if your method is not part of the WinAPI you should probably define your own type mapper, using that one as a template.

Comment: Hmm. I am implementing. Hoping for the best. LOL

Comment: Got this error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
 at com.sun.jna.Native.getWideString(Native Method)
 at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getWideString(Pointer.java:659)

Comment: It's possible `String` is not the right mapping. What is the definition of that method in the original API?

Comment: You mean the original DllFile.h? It's char. I think.

Comment: char or char* ? Does it define a fixed length array or ask you to pass a buffer?

Comment: It does not give a fixed length. Char in my origial DLLfile.h. Such as char FirstPath[], and so on for second and third parameter.

Comment: It doesnt like W32APIOptions.Default. Won't do anything after I remove BufferedWriter line and the rest of it.

Comment: "doesn't like" and "won't do anything" doesn't give us useful debugging tips to help you.  Please be specific on error messages and behavior.   Note that `char[]` is a fixed length array which would be a `byte[]` in Java.  Not sure it would help but consider using `String.getBytes()` and passing the resulting byte array to your method.  You may have to specify the `UTF-16` charset.

Comment: I am sorry. I mean it didn't give me any error when I used W32APIApotions.Default. Nothing.

Comment: It was supposed to write to a different file based on given paths. I didn't see any changes.

Comment: I'd love to try to help more but with you obfuscating the actual DLL name it's really hard to try to reproduce your problem.  If you can provide information on the original DLL and the exact code you're using we can try to help further.

Comment: I have added my DllFile.h. That should be all there.